# MongoDB Triggers update field when update even is fired

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to combine data from 2 collections on insert / update event.

I'm doing the update like this:

```
collection.updateOne(
          { _id: fullDocument._id },
          { $set: { fieldToUpdate: newData } }
        )
```

Since I'm updating the same document, the result is that the update event keeps firing in an endless loop.

Is there a way to update the document that is being processed on the insert / update event so that the update event wouldn't be triggered again?

Comment: Check whether the new data you are writing is the same as existing data, in this case don't write.

Comment: @D.SM It seems like there is no way to know what was the previous data. You only get the updated data.

Currently, as a workaround, I'm changing the structure of the field, that way I can now if it is the initial update trigger, or is the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a conditional update with the new value:

```
collection.updateOne(
          { _id: fullDocument._id, fieldToUpdate: {$ne: newData} },
          { $set: { fieldToUpdate: newData } }
        )
```